# Simple quote with my query

Tags: php

I'm stuck guys with my query, I'm pretty sure it's because of the quote .

I tried many things, `".$id."` or `'$id'` but I'm still geting the same error.

In Firebug (in my console), this is what I get . 
Thanks.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE cat= '.2.' ORDER BY id' at line 1
)
1
```

The mistake is on this line (in my query) :

```
$requete = "SELECT id, marque, cat FROM cars ORDER BY id WHERE cat= '.$id.' ORDER BY id";
```

The code :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$o = new stdClass(); // on déclare un tableau associatif

 // Connexion à la base de données
    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', '', '');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        exit('Impossible de se connecter à la base de données.');
    }

// Listes liées
if(isset($_GET['go']) || isset($_GET['id_marque'])) {

    $dropdown = array();

    if(isset($_GET['go'])) {
        // requête qui récupère les marques
        $requete = "SELECT id, marque FROM cars ORDER BY id";
    } else if(isset($_GET['id_marque'])) {
        $id = htmlentities(intval($_GET['id_marque']));
        // requête qui récupère les modeles selon la marque
        $requete = "SELECT id, marque, cat FROM cars ORDER BY id WHERE cat= '.$id.' ORDER BY id";
    }

    // Exécution de la requête
    $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
    $count= $resultat->rowCount();

    // Résultats
    while($donnees = $resultat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // je remplis un tableau et mettant l'id en index (que ce soit pour les marques ou les modeles)
        $dropdown[$donnees['id']][] = utf8_encode($donnees['id']);
    }

    // Envoi du résultat au success
    $o->dropdown = $dropdown;
    $o->count = $count;
}

// Autres liste
if(isset($_GET['go2'])) {

}

echo json_encode($o);

?>
```

Comment: Change `WHERE cat= '.$id.'` to `WHERE cat= '{$id}'`

Comment: you have 2 order by's. not working

Comment: I'm stupid, i didn't see that i have two ORDER BY... And what about the quote, what is the correct way to put a variable in a query ?

Comment: its the issue with variable concatenation in the SQL statement, use `'".$id."'` instead of `'.$id.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As already mentioned, remove the `.` from your query.
2. As already mentioned, you've two `ORDER BY` clauses.

Change the query to:

```
"SELECT id, marque, cat FROM cars WHERE cat= '{$id}' ORDER BY id";
```

Assuming from the output you get, `$id` should be an integer; then you can use:

```
"SELECT id, marque, cat FROM cars WHERE cat= {$id} ORDER BY id";
```

---

PS: If you already are filtering the results for `cat = $id`, why would you select that column for the result?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is `'".$id."'` and with only one `ORDER BY`

```
$requete = "SELECT id, marque, cat FROM cars WHERE cat= '".$id."' ORDER BY id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant (and wrong) `ORDER BY` clause before your `WHERE` clause - just remove it:

```
$requete = "SELECT id, marque, cat FROM cars WHERE cat='$id' ORDER BY id";
```